# Syncing selected nodes in multiple JTree objects

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'd like to have several `JTree`s (all with very similar content) have their selected nodes in sync (when the same node exists in each tree).

At the moment I'm doing this by adding a `TreeSelectionListener` to each tree and calling `setSelectedPath` on the other trees (if the `getSelectedPaths` doesn't contain the path).

However, I've seen this lead to infinite cycles, where each tree is repeatedly selecting different nodes (I'm not sure how to reproduce this, but I've seen it when dragging nodes).

There doesn't appear to be a way to set the selected path without triggering the tree selection listener, and I'd rather not go down the path of trying to remove listeners.

I'm considering the possibility of sharing a `TreeSelectionModel` between the trees, but this looks like a lot of work given the size of `DefaultTreeSelectionModel`.

Are there any other ways to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a flag isAPI. Set the flag when you programmatically select paths in the trees and reset it after path is set.

In the listeners just check whether the isAPI==true and return from the listener.

Comment: I'd originally discounted this as I was calling setSelectionPath in a call to `SwingUtilities2.invokeLater` which is it turns out is  unnecessary as the `TreeSelectionListener` will always be invoked on the GUI event dispatch thread.